# I don't know how to read the EXCEL file in Octave

Tags: octave

I downloaded the io Package and tried to read the dataset. But the error message is as follows:

```
warning: Functions for spreadsheet style I/O (.xls .xlsx .sxc .ods .dbf .wk1
etc.)  are provided in the io package.  See
<https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/>.

Please read <https://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
error: 'xlsread' undefined near line 4 column 17
error: called from
    Import_Data at line 4 column 16
```

```
    % Quarterly
    DATASET.TSERIES=xlsread(’MR_AER_DATASET.xlsx’,’Quarterly’,’A1:V229’);
    DATASET.LABEL ={’DATES’,’T_PI’,’T_CI’,’m_PI’,’m_CI’,’APITR’,’ACITR’,’PITB’,’CITB’,’GOV’};
    DATASET.VALUE   = [  1,       2,     3,     4,    5 ,    6 ,     7 ,     8  ,   9 ,    10 ];
    DATASET.UNIT    = [  0,       2,     2,     2,    2 ,    2,      2 ,     1  ,   1 ,    1  ];
```

Comment: Have you installed the io package? See output from `pkg list`.

Comment: The io package and spreadsheet support is generally very good but takes some finicky configuration. Find all the relevant information here: https://wiki.octave.org/IO_package